# Android application development, scroll views methods

Tags: android

I want to implement this method to my apps, but I don't know what it called.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/85u6WD8tFpuVBkdy9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `ViewPager`. It can slide between `Fragments` or really any `View`:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

Also, in that example, the page indicators are dots. You can see how to do that here:

https://riptutorial.com/android/example/22945/viewpager-with-a-dots-indicator

Comment: Hey thanks! Finally man, thanks for answering. I appreciate it .